# How can I get my setup.py to use a relative path to my files?

Tags: python, distutils

I'm trying to build a Python distribution with `distutils`.  Unfortunately, my directory structure looks like this:

```
/code
    /mypackage
        __init__.py
        file1.py
        file2.py
        /subpackage
            __init__.py
    /build
        setup.py
```

Here's my `setup.py` file:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name = 'MyPackage',
    description = 'This is my package',
    packages = ['mypackage', 'mypackage.subpackage'], 
    package_dir = { 'mypackage' : '../mypackage' }, 
    version = '1',
    url = 'http://www.mypackage.org/',
    author = 'Me',
    author_email = 'me@here.com',
)
```

When I run `python setup.py sdist` it correctly generates the manifest file, but doesn't include my source files in the distribution.  Apparently, it creates a directory to contain the source files (i.e. `mypackage1`) then copies each of the source files to `mypackage1/../mypackage` which puts them *outside* of the distribution.

How can I correct this, without forcing my directory structure to conform to what `distutils` expects?

Answer (score 7):

What directory structure do you want inside of the distribution archive file? The same as your existing structure?

You could package everything one directory higher (`code` in your example) with this modified setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name = 'MyPackage',
    description = 'This is my package',
    packages = ['mypackage', 'mypackage.subpackage'], 
    version = '1',
    url = 'http://www.mypackage.org/',
    author = 'Me',
    author_email = 'me@here.com',
    script_name = './build/setup.py',
    data_files = ['./build/setup.py']
)
```

You'd run this (in the `code` directory):

```
python build/setup.py sdist
```

Or, if you want to keep `dist` inside of build:

```
python build/setup.py sdist --dist-dir build/dist
```

I like the directory structure you're trying for. I've never thought `setup.py` was special enough to warrant being in the root code folder. But like it or not, I think that's where users of your distribution will expect it to be. So it's no surprise that you have to trick distutils to do something else. The `data_files` parameter is a hack to get your setup.py into the distribution in the same place you've located it.

Comment: I don't much care what the structure in the distribution file looks like, as long as it does the right thing when users try and install it using easy_install.  But the Python documentation is absolutely horrible when it comes to these details--I have no idea what the structure is even supposed to look like.  And I'm still wrapping my head around the idea that you run a script in the distribution before it's installed in order to install the distribution.

Answer (score 3):

Have it change to the parent directory first, perhaps?

```
import os
os.chdir(os.pardir)

from distutils.core import setup
```

etc.

Or if you might be running it from anywhere (this is overkill, but...):

```
import os.path
my_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
os.chdir(os.normpath(os.path.join(my_path, os.pardir)))
```

etc. Not sure this works, but should be easy to try.

Answer (score 2):

**Run setup.py from the root folder of the project**

In your case, place setup.py in code/

code/ should also include:

- LICENSE.txt
- README.txt
- INSTALL.txt
- TODO.txt
- CHANGELOG.txt

The when you run "setup.py sdist' it should auto-gen a MANIFEST including:
 - any files specified in py_modules and/or packages
 - setup.py 
 - README.txt

To add more files just hand-edit the MANIFEST file to include whatever other files your project needs.

For a somewhat decent explanation of this [read this](http://docs.python.org/release/1.6/dist/manifest.html).

To see a working example checkout [my project](http://code.google.com/p/pypreprocessor/source/browse/).

*Note: I don't put the MANIFEST under version control so you won't find it there.*

Answer (score 0):

A sorta lame workaround but I'd probably just use a Makefile that rsynced ./mypackage to ./build/mypackage and then use the usual distutils syntax from inside ./build. Fact is, distutils expects to unpack setup.py into the root of the sdist and have code under there, so you're going to have a devil of time convincing it to do otherwise.

You can always nuke the copy when you make clean so you don't have to mess up your vcs.

Answer (score 0):

Also a lame workaround, but a junction/link of the package directory inside of the build project should work.