# Python distutils setup relative paths for package_dir

Tags: python, distutils

I've looked here:
[How can I get my setup.py to use a relative path to my files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812242/how-can-i-get-my-setup-py-to-use-a-relative-path-to-my-files)
and here:
[python distutils does not include data_files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994396/python-distutils-does-not-include-data-files)

and here:
 [Confused about the package_dir and packages settings in setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155804/confused-about-the-package-dir-and-packages-settings-in-setup-py)
but found no love.

I suspect that distutils doesn't support the directory structure I'm trying to use but would love confirmation and/or suggestion for how to improve.

I have the following directory structure:

```
/src  
├── user 
├── admin  
│   ├── admin.py  
│   ├── LICENSE.txt  
│   ├── MANIFEST  
│   ├── MANIFEST.in  
│   ├── README.txt  
│   └── setup.py  
└── lib  
    ├── __init__.py  
    ├── __init__.pyc  
    ├── rcodes.py  
    ├── rcodes.pyc  
    ├── validation.py  
    └── validation.pyc
```

Where several projects in src depend on the lib package. However, when trying to run the setup.py in /src/admin I can not include the lib dir in the final package (using setup.py sdist).

Setup.py is as follows:
from distutils.core import setup

```
setup(
name='admin_server',
version='0.0.0',
author='Instamrkt',
author_email='info@instamrkt.com',
url='http://instamrkt.com',
description='Instamrkt Admin Server',
packages=['lib'],
package_dir = {'lib': '../lib'},
py_modules = [
'admin',
'lib.rcodes',
'lib.validation'
],)
```

Which yields:

```
[foozle@ip-172-31-36-251 admin]$ python setup.py sdist
running sdist
running check
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'MANIFEST'
creating admin_server-0.0.0
making hard links in admin_server-0.0.0...
hard linking README.txt -> admin_server-0.0.0
hard linking admin.py -> admin_server-0.0.0
hard linking setup.py -> admin_server-0.0.0
Creating tar archive
removing 'admin_server-0.0.0' (and everything under it)
[foozle@ip-172-31-36-251 admin]$ tar tzf ./dist/admin_server-0.0.0.tar.gz
admin_server-0.0.0/
admin_server-0.0.0/PKG-INFO
admin_server-0.0.0/admin.py
admin_server-0.0.0/setup.py
admin_server-0.0.0/README.txt
```

The package lib is missing.

And just to be explicit I would like the same directory structure preserved in the package so that I can use lib in multiple distributions for different apps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create a source distribution when using the package_dir option to point to an upstream directory ('../lib'), because sdist will copy the whole source tree as is, and '../lib' ends up outside of the build tree.

You can however create a binary distribution:

```
python setup.py bdist
```

or, if using setuptools:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

The later has the advantage of creating a system-agnostic distribution if your module is pure Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the default sdist command and overwrite the methods which copy the files.

Check make_distribution() and make_release_tree()

```
class rel_sdist(sdist):
    pass

setup(
    ...
    cmdclass={'sdist': rel_sdist},
)
```