# Google Dataflow non-python dependencies - separate setup.py?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We need a non-Python dependency installed into our Dataflow process (we need an ODBC driver to access an MSSQL DB)

We've written a `setup.py` that successfully installs those using the steps here: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/dependencies-python#non-python-dependencies

We want to keep our original `setup.py` for the package (which doesn't install those extra dependencies); is there a way of using a different `setup.py` for Dataflow installs?

We tried:

- calling it `setup_dataflow.py`, but Dataflow raised an error stating it needed to be called `setup.py`.
- following the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/814118/3064736), and using a `setup.py` within a child path to the root path. We weren't successful at that

We could try a `if` statement within `setup.py` to identify whether it's being installed in a Dataflow environment (though I couldn't find any reliable environment variables to identify this)

Any advice / suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: How do you schedule your job to DataFlow?

Comment: Currently from the command line (similar to the standard examples)

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's no convenient way to do this. You could have two different packages, something like so:

```
+- dataflow_pipeline
++- setup.py
+- original_pipeline
++- setup.py
++- pipeline.py
```

Where `dataflow_pipeline/setup.py` simply imports `original_package`, and adds the extra dependencies.

It's not ideal, but it should work.

Comment: How would you get the `original_pipeline` installed? Build and ship as an `extra_package`?