# How could code know it's running on Google Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'd like to use some configs for a library that's used both on Dataflow and in a normal environment.

Is there a way for the code to check it's running on Dataflow? I couldn't see an environment variable, for example.

Quasi-follow-up to [Google Dataflow non-python dependencies - separate setup.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47044216/google-dataflow-non-python-dependencies-separate-setup-py/47081311#47081311)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a good answer, but it may be the best we can do at the moment:

```
if 'harness' in os.environ.get('HOSTNAME', ''):
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use PipelineOptions, which contains the pipeline runner information. As mentioned in the beam documentation: "When you run the pipeline on a runner of your choice, a copy of the PipelineOptions will be available to your code. For example, you can read PipelineOptions from a DoFn’s Context."

More about PipelineOptions: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#configuring-pipeline-options

Comment: How would you access the options in DataFlow?

Comment: You can use getPipelineOptions in a DoFn: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/0.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/DoFn.Context.html#getPipelineOptions--

Comment: Thanks. Any idea of how to do that in Python? Looks like it's not available here: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params . But often stuff is in the code even when it's not in the DataFlow docs

Comment: Unfortunately, the Python SDK currently does not support getting PipelineOptions in a DoFn :(